# Error Propagation in Oracle Function

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a Oracle function which has the following structure

```
Function TEST_FUNC(o_err_msg varchar2)
return BOOLEAN
is
begin
for C in 1..10
 loop
    begin
         insert into test
         values(c);
         return true;
    exception
      when no_data_found
            null;
      return true;
      when others then
            ---Some Code
         return false;
    end;
end loop;
end;
```

when I run this I get ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value. How to make sure that when the inner BLOCK Returns TRUE the function RETURN TRUE and when return FALSE it RETURN FALSE.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not getting any exceptions - so the LOOP executes successfully but there's no return statement after the LOOP has completed. You need to add one:

```
Function test_func(o_err_msg varchar2) return boolean is
begin
   for c in 1..10 loop
      begin
         insert into test
         values(c);
      exception
         when no_data_found
           return true;
         when others then
            ---Some Code
            return false;
       end;
   end loop;
   return True;
end test_func;
```

Other problems:

- An INSERT statement will not return a NO_DATA_FOUND exception, this is raised when using SELECT INTO (maybe you meant DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX?)
- Please indent!
- It's helpful for later if you end your function with the function name, this just helps with clarity.
- If you're actually doing this then a single INSERT statement may be preferable.